# Re-writing query to avoid WHERE IN with a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-in

I have the following query which returns the correct results but I am aware of the overheads associated with subqueries in a WHERE IN clause.

```
SELECT event_start_date 
  FROM events
       JOIN joins 
            ON event_id = join_event_id
       JOIN groups 
            ON join_type_id IN (SELECT group_id 
                                  FROM view_groups 
                                 WHERE user_id = 3)
 WHERE user_id = 3
       AND event_start_date >= now()
GROUP BY 
       event_start_date;
```

Can anyone help out with rewriting this query to avoid the subquery and/or the WHERE IN clause.

Comment: How about: add one more `JOIN` for view_groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does [optimize uncorrelated subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimizing-subqueries.html) (which you have in your example):

> MySQL executes uncorrelated subqueries only once. Use EXPLAIN to make
>   sure that a given subquery really is uncorrelated.

If your subquery returns only one result, be sure to use equal instead:

> For uncorrelated subqueries that always return one row, IN is always
>   slower than =.

Regardless, this is how you rewrite your query as a JOIN:

```
SELECT events.event_start_date 
  FROM events
       JOIN joins 
            ON events.event_id = joins.join_event_id
       JOIN view_groups
            ON view_groups.user_id = 3
       JOIN groups 
            ON groups.join_type_id = view_groups.group_id
 WHERE events.user_id = 3
       AND events.event_start_date >= NOW()
 GROUP BY 
       events.event_start_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 SELECT event_start_date FROM events
 JOIN joins ON event_id = join_event_id
 join view_groups on ............condition here
 JOIN groups ON join_type_id = view_groups.group_id 
 WHERE user_id = 3
 AND event_start_date >= now()
 GROUP BY event_start_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

Also, Why are you using a Group by without an aggregate function in Select?

```
SELECT event_start_date
FROM events
INNER JOIN joins
    ON event_id = join_event_id
WHERE user_id = 3
    AND event_start_date >= now()
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT group_id
        FROM view_groups
        WHERE user_id = 3
            AND group_id = join_type_id
        )
GROUP BY event_start_date;
```